# Data not scraped in XML or JSON using scrapy

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape match schedules from a url. Using `scrapy shell` I am able to get the results that are required. But when done through a `spider`, no data is retrieved. This is how I am doing it:

```
class ScheduleSpider (Spider):
    name = "fplscheduler"
    allowed_domains = ["fantasy.premierleague.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.premierleague.com/en-gb/matchday/matches.html?paramClubId=ALL&paramComp_100=true&view=.dateSeason"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        completeSchedule= hxs.select("//div[@class='fixturelist section']//table[@class='contentTable']//tr")
        items = []
        for schedule in completeSchedule:
            item = FplserviceItem()
            item["time"] = schedule.select("td[@class='time']//text").extract()
            item["matchDate"] = schedule.select("th[@colspan='6']//text").extract()
            item["match"] = schedule.select("td[@class='clubs']//text").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

One of the commands run on shell to get the matches over the `start_url`:

```
sel.xpath("//div[@class='fixturelist section']//table[@class='contentTable']//tr//td[@class='clubs']//text()").extract()
```

This is the command I run to generate an `xml`:

```
scrapy crawl fplscheduler -o schedule.xml -t xml
```

This is the output of my xml file:

```
<items><item><match/><matchDate/><time/></item><item><match/><matchDate/><time/></item><item><match/><matchDate/><time/></item><item><match/><matchDate/><time/></item><item><match/><matchDate/><time/></item>....</items>
```

Nodes have no data in them.

What have I done wrong here?

**UPDATE**
These are the changes that are made:

```
for schedule in completeSchedule:
            item = FplserviceItem()
            item["time"] = schedule.select("td[@class='time']//text()").extract()
            item["matchDate"] = schedule.select("th[@colspan='6']//text()").extract()
            item["match"] = schedule.select("td[@class='clubs']//a/text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Now this is the output:

```
<items><item><match/><matchDate><value>Saturday 1 March 2014 </value></matchDate><time/></item><item><match><value>Everton v West Ham</value></match><matchDate/><time><value>15:00</value></time></item>...</items>
```

Each object now contains one value per node. I need it like this:

```
<items><item><match><value>Everton v West Ham</value></match><matchDate><value>Saturday 1 March 2014 </value></matchDate><time><value>15:00</value></time></item>...</items>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the simplest method, but it outputs the information in the required format. Please test it out and let me know if any adjustments are needed. :)

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    completeSchedule= hxs.select("//div[@class='fixturelist section']//table[@class='contentTable']")
    items = []
    for schedule in completeSchedule:
        matchDate = schedule.select("tr//th[@colspan='6']/text()").extract()[0]
        times = schedule.select("tr//td[@class='time']//text()").extract()
        matches = schedule.select("tr//td[@class='clubs']//a/text()").extract()

        for m, t in zip(matches, times):
            item = FplserviceItem()
            item["matchDate"] = matchDate
            item["match"] = m
            item["time"] = t
            items.append(item)
    return items
```

Answer (score 2):

the xpath in your scrapy shell is not the same as in your spider.

1.change `text` to `text()` in your spider xpath

```
item["time"] = schedule.select("td[@class='time']//text()").extract()
item["match"] = schedule.select("td[@class='clubs']//a/text()").extract()
```

2.also add `a` to `clubs` class to refine the extracted text

3.not sure what did you try to scrape with `matchDate`

EDIT: you'll have to avoid getting into `tr` in the loop as `matchDate` it placed in a different row than the other two, instead do something like:

```
completeSchedule= hxs.select("//div[@class='fixturelist section']//table[@class='contentTable']")
items = []
for schedule in completeSchedule:
    item = FplserviceItem()
    item["time"] = schedule.select("tr//td[@class='time']//text()").extract()
    item["matchDate"] = schedule.select("tr//th[@colspan='6']//strong[1]/text()").extract()
    item["match"] = schedule.select("tr//td[@class='clubs']//a/text()").extract()
    items.append(item)
return items
```

Comment: I made the changes that you pointed out. Well, now I am getting the data, but in a strange manner.. My `xml` is: `<item><match/><matchDate><value>Saturday 1 March 2014 </value></matchDate><time/></item><item><match><value>Everton v West Ham</value></match><matchDate/><time><value>15:00</value></time></item>`.. I suppose some error in parsing..